# Why can't I send some crash reports to Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting

Why can't I send some problem reports to Microsoft?

[image: problem reports on windows 10]

Double clicking a problem or using the right click menu to open `view technical details` there is no option to send the problem to Microsoft. It should appear as it did on some issues, so why not others? Like those three?

Comment: Were these reports sent as the same user?  [RunDll32.exe "C:\Windows\system32\WerConCpl.dll", LaunchErcApp -updatecheck](https://serverfault.com/questions/616324/is-there-a-command-to-send-windows-error-reports-wer) appears to be the command that is required

Comment: Check if in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting` you have an item called "Disabled". If it exists, delete it and reboot.

Comment: Yes it's all from the same user.

Comment: I tried the command and the 3 problem reports are still not sent.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing a screen shot of Reliability History. I am very familiar with this report.

The items in bold have not yet worked through the reliability system. It may take a day or two.

Wait until the 3 reports clear and show as normal type / reported.

It may take a day or two, but the reports eventually will report to Microsoft. You cannot hurry the process.

**Additional Note**:

If you wish (take care), you can clear Reliability History. I do this so I only see current history.

In this article  [Clear reliability batch file](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-reliability-monitor-windows)

Go to the line:

> Firstly download the batch file from our servers by clicking *here*.

This will download a ZIP file. Expand it to Reset-Reliability-Monitor.bat  . I have this file and the current download compares bitwise exactly.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
Run the batch file and let it finish.
Close this.
Run Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup, click on Cleanup System Files. Select all items, and OK.

This should clear Reliability History and let you concentrate on new errors.

Comment: But one is from December 2020 and another one is from January 2021, so shouldn't if of sent by now?

Comment: Try restarting the machine and then look at Reliability History again. The hard shut down may take some time - that is what has happened to me.

Comment: I amended my answer to include a section on clearing reliability history. I find that useful from time to time.

Comment: Restarting my computer does not make the 3 problem reports get sent.

Comment: Clean up history as I showed in my answer. I a not sure why not sent but clear them out as they are now too old to send.